# How do I get 'rake test:acceptance' to run successfully on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium

I am currently investigating using the selenium-on-rails plug-in for testing an upcoming web app that we are developing.
I've written some tests, and can get them to run successfully in the test runner in the browser, however when I try to run them from the command line using 'rake test:acceptance' I see the following error:

```
rake aborted!
fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
```

I have installed the win32-open3 gem and win32-process, neither of these seem to have helped.
Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by adding the following to the top of acceptance_test_runner.rb:

```
require 'win32/open3'
require 'win32/process'
```

However the script was also determining my platform as 'i386-mingw32', which does not match the regexp the script uses to determine if you are on windows /mswin/.
Resolved this second issue by manually specifying

```
RUBY_PATH=mswin
```

Phew.